# Editing an external library

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an external library in the project:

[image]

The project uses methods from this library

For me, the classes in this library are read-only

I need to change the method logic from an external library a little bit

What and how should I do?

Maybe I should create new class in project with the same logic? (+ my changes)

Maybe other solutions?

Comment: Maybe you could EXTEND that or create a whole new Class that inclused an Object made with that Class and replicate all the methods/fields in this new extension. The other way could be to decompile the Library, edit it and then recompile it without bothering to use the same signature/key.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Kotlin` you could use `Extension Function` to extend class functionalities with no need to `extend` it. You use `Java` you could extend the classes and `override` or `add` methods to it. There is no need to copy/paste class to add new functionalities.