# Vscode: edit an external java libray

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Debugging a maven project with external java jar dependencies. Attached sources can be opened and java source is shown fine (its opened as `*.class`, though, not `*.java`). Unfortunately vscode denies changing that code with **Cannot edit in read-only editor**. <s>In eclipse this was possible by simply attaching the source jar.</s> Is there a way to manipulate the external library by changing the java source jar?
(Similiar question: [Editing an external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58396869/editing-an-external-library))

Comment: Hm. Just tried to edit a jar-"source" file in eclipse as claimed by me, but this is indeed  _not_ possible, even not in eclipse. Don't know, maybe I had just copied the source file of the external library into my project to be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems not possible. As an alternative one could copy the class into the local project and import that one directly and manipulate it. Or use a wrapper.

In my case, I just wanted to print objects for debugging purpose. For this there *is* a nice feature in visual studio code: use the `Debug Console` where you can type commands!

It's done like this:
Debug your program with breakpoints set in the dependency class, wait until the debugger stops there. Then look into the `Debug Console`. At the end of that window is a prompt `>`. Type e.g. `String s = key.toString()` and hit your `enter` key. Marvel at the output in that console.